# Java code to convert country codes alpha-2 (IN) to alpha 3 (IND)

Tags: java, locale, country-codes

Using Java, Is there a quick way to convert an alpha-2 country code (IN or GB) 
to the alpha-3 equivalent (IND or GBR)?

I can get the alpha-2 codes with:

> String[] codes = java.util.Locale.getISOLanguages();

That's not a problem, actually my application reads in the alpha-2 code, but I need to output the alpha-3 equivalent .

Is there a similar way like above to get the alpha-3 codes?

Any suggestions?

Comment: This code can be used, for conversion vice versa from Alpha-3 into Alpha-2:
`Map<String, String> countryCodeMap = Stream.of(Locale.getAvailableLocales())
                .filter(locale -> !locale.getISO3Country().isEmpty())
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Locale::getISO3Country, Locale::getCountry));
countryCodeMap.get("IND")`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This works -

```
    Locale locale = new Locale("en","IN");
    System.out.println("Country=" + locale.getISO3Country());
```

Output:

```
Country=IND
```

Comment: This is great, as I can swop in a variable containing the new country code each time, and it will give me back the corresponding 3 char code for every country.

Locale locale = new Locale("en",myCode); 

The language will all be english, but I'm not concerned about language.

Answer (score 13):

Yes, simple create a Locale and get if from the locale:

```
String alpha3Country = new Locale("en", alpha2County).getISO3Country();
```

BTW: `getISOLanguages()` returns language codes (lowercase), `getISOCountries()` return country codes (uppercase)

Comment: This is great, as I can swop in a variable containing the new country code each time, and it will give me back the corresponding 3 char code for every country. 

The language will all be english, but I'm not concerned about language.

Comment: On a side note, you can equivalently do `new Locale("", alpha2County).getISO3Country()`. Specifying the English language here is kind of irrelevant.

Comment: Faulty BTW: Country codes are UPPERCASE, language codes lowercase.

Answer (score 5):

Since you read in the codes, you can't hardcode them you rather should create a lookup table to convert into ISO codes.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // setup
        Locale[] availableLocales = Locale.getAvailableLocales();
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        for ( Locale l : availableLocales ) {
            map.put( l.getCountry(), l.getISO3Country() );
        }
        // usage
        System.out.println( map.get( "IN" ) );
        System.out.println( map.get( "GB" ) );
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Gopi's answer works. **BUT** take note that the returned codes are the ISO 3166 country codes and not the ISO 4217 currency codes. These differ slightly so use with caution

Comment: Please, try to read this http://stackoverflow.com/about, to get more understanding about questions/answers here on SO. Your contribution is not answering the question. It is more a comment, which you can add once you'll increase your reputation: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation